# how to return loop and array element | Data location must be "memory" for return parameter in function | Dynamic Array

Tags: ethereum, solidity

I am using the following code to return array.

```
 function getActiveDepositIndexes() public view returns (uint256 [] storage) {
    User storage user = users[msg.sender];
    Deposit[] storage deposits = user.deposits;
    uint[] memory indices = new uint[](deposits.length);
    for(uint i = 0; i < deposits.length; i++) {
        if(deposits[i].active && !deposits[i].closed){
            indices.push(i);
        }
    }
    return indices;
 }
```

But I am getting following error,

```
TypeError: Data location must be "memory" for return parameter in function, but "storage" was given.
     function getActiveDepositIndexes() public view returns (uint256 [] storage) {
                                                             ^----------------^
```

Environment:

```
Truffle v5.1.20 (core: 5.1.20)
Solidity - 0.6.0 (solc-js)
Node v8.16.2
Web3.js v1.2.1
```

Comment: And why is the 'storege' used in the return, and not the 'memory'?

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you explicitly specify `storage` for function return value. Try replacing your function signature with the following:

```
function getActiveDepositIndexes() public view returns (uint[]) {...}
```

`memory` is used for return values by default

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code instead:

```
function getActiveDepositIndexes() public view returns (uint256[] memory) {
    User storage user = users[msg.sender];
    Deposit[] storage deposits = user.deposits;
    uint[] memory indices = new uint[](deposits.length);
    for(uint i = 0; i < deposits.length; i++) {
        if(deposits[i].active && !deposits[i].closed){
            indices[i] = i;
        }
    }
    return indices;
 }
```

Issues with such logic on EVM is that there is no way of returning dynamic sized memory arrays and hence push() is also not usuable with memory elements. This workaround in the above example results in zero (placeholder) alues at inactive indices according to your code...